How to convert price strings like "10.99 USD" or "10,99 EUR" into numbers in JavaScript?
I am creating template ads in Google Web Designer for Google Ads. The problem is that the price from the feed is providing prices in formats like this:

1,200.99 USD (Currency at the end)
1.200,99 EUR (Spanish format)
AED 1,200.99 (With currency in front)

And I am using Javascript to take these prices and make some math with price and discounted price to get the percentage off. The problem I am facing is that it only works in Google preview. When the ads are live, the prices are sometimes shown like this, without the dots or any formating:

$120099
€120099
120099AED

The logic I am using is:

replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')
Number()
Assembling back the currency (with Intl.NumberFormat() it is returning same issue)

I feel like Google is changing the data from the feed before putting the ad live. Here's the full code:
 const frames = this.querySelectorAll('.frame')
    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
      const country = 'UK' //CHANGE COUNTRY HERE, use NA for AU, NL for BE_nl and FR for BE_fr
      const value = frames[i].querySelector('[data-gwd-grp-id="value"]')
      const price = frames[i].querySelector('[data-gwd-grp-id="price"]')
      const salePrice = frames[i].querySelector('[data-gwd-grp-id="sale-price"]')
      const description = frames[i].querySelector('[data-gwd-grp-id="description"]')
      const cta = frames[i].querySelector('[data-gwd-grp-id="cta"]')
      const priceNumber = Number(price.innerHTML.replace(/[^.\d]/g, ''))
      const salePriceNumber = Number(salePrice.innerHTML.replace(/[^.\d]/g, ''))
      const percentage = Math.floor(100 - ((salePriceNumber * 100) / priceNumber))
      const countries = {
        NA: {
          cta: "See Deal",
          value: `${percentage}% OFF`,
          price: `$${priceNumber}`,
          salePrice: `$${salePriceNumber}`
        },
        UK: {
          cta: "See Deal",
          value: `${percentage}% OFF`,
          price: `£${priceNumber}`,
          salePrice: `£${salePriceNumber}`
        },
        IE: {
          cta: "See Deal",
          value: `${percentage}% OFF`,
          price: `${priceNumber} €`,
          salePrice: `${salePriceNumber} €`
        },
        AE: {
          cta: "See Deal",
          value: `${percentage}% OFF`,
          price: `AED${priceNumber}`,
          salePrice: `AED${salePriceNumber}`
        },
        NL: {
          cta: "Zie deal",
          value: `${percentage}% KORTING`,
          price: `${priceNumber} €`,
          salePrice: `${salePriceNumber} €`
        },
        FR: {
          cta: "Voir l'offre",
          value: `${percentage}% Réduction`,
          price: `${priceNumber} €`,
          salePrice: `${salePriceNumber} €`
        },
        DE: {
          cta: "Siehe Deal",
          value: `${percentage}% SPAREN`,
          price: `€${priceNumber}`,
          salePrice: `€${salePriceNumber}`
        },
        IT: {
          cta: "Scopri",
          value: `${percentage}% di sconto`,
          price: `${priceNumber} €`,
          salePrice: `${salePriceNumber} €`
        },
        ES: {
          cta: "Ver oferta",
          value: `${percentage}% dto.`,
          price: `${priceNumber} €`,
          salePrice: `${salePriceNumber} €`
        },
        PL: {
          cta: "Patrz oferta",
          value: `${percentage}% ZNIŻKI`,
          price: `${priceNumber} zł`,
          salePrice: `${salePriceNumber} zł`
        }
      }
      cta.innerHTML = countries[country].cta
      price.innerHTML = countries[country].price
      salePrice.innerHTML = countries[country].salePrice
      if (percentage > 0 && percentage < 100 && price && salePrice) {
        value.innerHTML = countries[country].value
      } else {
        value.style.display = "none"
      }
      if (priceNumber === salePriceNumber) price.style.display = "none"
      if (price < 0.01) price.style.display = "none"
      if (salePriceNumber < 0.01) salePrice.style.display = "none"
      if (description.innerHTML === '') description.style.display = "none"
    }


Use a regex with parseFloat and stripping commas and dots except the last one. But this approach works only if the decimal part is presented otherwise you need to know the locale a currency belongs to, so you need to parse each currency individually.


const parseCurrency = str => {
  const parts = str.match(/[\d,.]+/)[0].split(/[,.]/);
  const last = parts.pop();
  return parseFloat(parts.join('') + '.' + last);
};
const result = ['1,200.99 USD', '1.200,99 EUR', 'AED 1,200.99'].map(parseCurrency);
console.log(...result);



